# What type of database to pick up to represent connections between natural language' words

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, nosql, graph-databases

Let's say we want to store a data that represents **all possible English words** (eventually), including all its **forms**, **synonyms**, **parts of speech**. Including **tenses**, **common expressions**, **idioms**. And even more - a lot of connections which we even do not know about right now.

**Requirements about searching through the words:** it should be **fast**. I could instantly want to get all idioms where word "go" is used. Or I can get **all words with 3 letters in it that are related to business (tag) and have the same form in all tenses.**

What kind of database you would use for that type of problem?

1. `NOSQL` database, like Mongo DB? Probably not - since there are a lot of connections. But in first glance it might be not bad idea - json could represents us picture clearly (for human) ?.
2. `Relational Database`, `SQL` one' like `MySql`, whateverSQL.. Maybe not - because three might lots of **joins**, many indexes and this might be even not enough? Or even if use clusters, then it might be mess to understand and support this structure ?
3. `[Graph database][1]` ? This seems all about links and connections between objects, and it seems much closer to `OO` way of representing data (easy to understand having marking connections by some names & types - like connection/association: synonym).But even though it might be slow comparing to relational db(if follow wikipedia)? (I've never worked with this type of dbs). And what about scaling (maybe those type of dbs are not yet proven for real tasks) ??
4. Create your own?(I would not go this way..)

**The questions are:**

1. Is there another type of db /representation of data You could use for this type of task?
2. Does someone have some strong proven opinion bases on some experience working with similar problems?

Comment: How about a semantic (RDF) database?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try going with a Graph database. You may find some inspiration in this talk: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/case-study-using-graph-theory-graph-databases-to-understand-user-intent/mh-6603

And just to neat-pick a bit: Graph databases are considered NoSQL as well. Check this great talk by Martin Fowler: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I

Comment: "N-gram" is something that might be interested for me. thanks for that direction.